# Not able to recreate Quad from .obj with only Face3

Tags: javascript, three.js, texture-mapping

I made a small tool where I could select faces of an object and get the lengths and angles of each side and corner. While updating to r67 of Three.js Face4 disappeared and I am having trouble recreating what I had before. n = (f instanceof THREE.Face3) ? 3 : 4 would make it so i could add 4 uv's to the Face4. But I do not see a way now to be know when there would have been a Face4 so I can add 2 Face3.

The code below is a function that takes the geometry of the obj.

```
 function draw(g)
    {
        objectContainer = new THREE.Object3D();

        texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('uvmap.png');
        texture.flipY = false;

        materials = [];
        materials.push(new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            map: texture,
            vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
        }));

        var faceIndices = ['a','b','c','d'];

        var color = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
        color.setHex(0x333333);

        var uvs = [];
        uvs.push(new THREE.Vector2(0,1));
        uvs.push(new THREE.Vector2(0,0));
        uvs.push(new THREE.Vector2(1,1));
        uvs.push(new THREE.Vector2(1,0));

        for (i = 0; i < g.faces.length; i++)
        {
            face = g.faces[i];
            geo = new THREE.Geometry();
            geo.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,1,2));
            geo.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];
            geo.faceVertexUvs[0].push([uvs[0], uvs[1], uvs[3]]);
            geo.faces[0].materialIndex = 0;

            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                fi = face[faceIndices[j]];
                v = g.vertices[fi];
                geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(v.x,v.y,v.z));
                geo.faces[0].vertexColors[j] = color;
            }

            geo.computeVertexNormals(); 
            geo.computeBoundingBox();

            obj = new THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geo, materials);

            objectContainer.add(obj);
        }
        scene.add(objectContainer);
    }
```

Comment: You are using a version of the library that is more than a year old. If  you want help, you should update to the current version, which no longer supports `Face4`, by the way.

Comment: will do! i thought it was more a mathematical problem rather than something affected by version.

Comment: Updated code, which now I have no idea how to even draw a quad texture.. + laptop goes to 100 degrees within a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting only 3 uv values on a face3 !

```
    /* create faces and uv's */
        if (n == 3)
        {
            g.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,1,2));
            g.faceVertexUvs[0].push([ uvs[0], uvs[1], uvs[2], uvs[3] ]);

        }
```

uvs [3] shouldn't be set !